# Unity destroy bullet after distance

Tags: unity-game-engine, distance, destroy, bullet

I want to make an FPS in Unity and I came across weapon range. I want an assault rifle to have 100m range so when I shoot a bullet from it the bullet should destroy after 100m. How can I do that? I use raycasts for direction with hit.point (with max distance) to know where my bullet hit. I know there is the function Destroy(seconds) which destroys the object after a float number of seconds. How can I destroy a bullet not after some time, but after some distance? Thanks in advance for every answer! :)

Comment: This is probably a better question for https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its really easy:

use [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) between initial position and the position bullet (transform.position) to calculate the distance .

```
 `Vector3.Distance(initialposition, transform.position)`
```

if > specified distance you destroy object

you could use another function: `(transform.position - initialposition).magnitude`

maybe better in performance if needed (i dunno)

Comment: well, I don't know why I didn't think about that. I feel so noob :). I searched into the documentation and I couldn't find anything, but I couldn't imagine that the answer is right in front of me :). thanks for your answer, Frenchy. Always helpful :)

Comment: Done, sorry for forgetting that this time.